# gmaps4rails: HOW TO automatically add makers for locations matching a key word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I need to add markers for locations matching a specific keyword on my map.
Such as "hotel" for instance.

I need to obtain the same result as when I search for that keyword on maps.google.com, only I want this search to be done automatically using gmaps4rails. I would add my location with a different marker on top.

cheers,

joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the process would be:

**Ajax version**

1. you already have a map from gmaps4rails displayed
2. submit a form remotely to your server
3. create the proper query on your records in your controller, simply respond with `.to_gmaps4rails`
4. use the js `replaceMarkers` function to clear the map and display the markers from the server response.
5. use the geolocation functions of the client browser (beware, not available on all of them) + the js `addMarkers` function to display the user position.
6. I wrote the [relevant documentation here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies)

**Standard version**

1. get the proper objects from your controller
2. create the json from them
3. create your map
4. add a js callback to create the marker with user's position